# Understanding the return type of the function

Tags: c, return-type

I am looking at this code passed onto me to resolve an issue but I have trouble understanding one of the function's definition.

`void DESC_API ApplDesc(DescMsg* pMsg)`

I can see that the function isnt returning anything so the `void` holds good. But what is the `DESC_API` doing in here? This is how it is defined in the header file

```
#if defined(DESC_API)
#else
 /* No paging used. */
#define DESC_API
#endif
```

Comment: Something in the build is likely to be defining DESC_API on the compiler command line.

Comment: It probably does nothing. I think it might be a hook for something (as described in the answers below) that was either never implemented or that is injected at compile time. Have you tried telling your compiler to do only the pre-proceessing part ('gcc -E', for example) to see what that resolves into? Maybe that'll give you more clues as to what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `DESC_API` a is visibility macro. It might be defined to `__declspec(dllexport)` or to `__declspec(dllimport)` for MSVC or to `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` for gcc or clang.

Of course, it might be defined to something else (as said bellow), but the most popular use case is just symbols visibility attributes.

Since gcc and clang export all symbols by default, no attributes is needed and `DESC_API` is blank. As for MSVC, your build system might set it via `/DDESC_API=__declspec(dllimport)` externally.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `DESC_API` could be used to switch between a function returning nothing and a function returning a `void*`.

If you define

```
#define DESC_API *
```

the function would be returning a void pointer; otherwise, the function would return nothing.

Of course the rest of the function must follow through with a conditional return based on the value of `DESC_API`.

Comment: Maybe, but the OP notes that the function doesn't return anything.  He might have failed to mention conditional compilation directives affecting that, but I think it's more likely that the macro's intended use is a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

The macro appears to be a hook by which additional qualifiers can be injected into function signatures.  I'm inclined to think that its intended usage is to leverage compiler-specific extensions under certain circumstances, such as to mark functions as using some particular calling convention.

Note that the macro definition you present is conditional.  It provides for the macro to be defined (with empty replacement text) in the event that it is not already defined, where a previous definition might come from another header or from a command-line option.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably does nothing, as you can see by the macro the DESC_API is replaced by blank, hence this is probably a macro used for readability convenience that's it though

Comment: Careful.  The code presented defines `DESC_API` as nothing only if it is not already defined.